# how to prevent chrome to autofill EVERY fields in a form?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, web

I have a website page with a simple form with 5 email fields. When I begin to fill the first field, chrome proposes me to fill EVERY fields with the same email address. I don't want to disable the chrome autofill feature completely (I know it is possible by adding the attribute `autocomplete="off"`).

Is it possible to let the autofill feature work just for each field individually?

Here's the form code:

```
<form action="#emails" method="POST" name="sponsorship_form_email" id="sponsorship_form_email" >
    <p>
        <label>Email 1 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email[]"  id="1"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email 2 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email[]"  id="2"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email 3 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email[]" id="3"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email 4 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email[]" id="4"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Email 5 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email[]" id="5"  />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input value="Invite"  id="send" type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your inputs different names ;)

```
<form action="#emails" method="POST" name="sponsorship_form_email" id="sponsorship_form_email" >

            <p>
                <label>Email 1 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email1"  id="1"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email 2 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email2"  id="2"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email 3 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email3" id="3"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email 4 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email4" id="4"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email 5 : </label><input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email5" id="5"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input value="Invite"  id="send" type="submit" />
            </p>

          </form>
```

Comment: That's what I tought but I didn't want to do that to avoid loosing the email[] array... Thanks anyway :)

Comment: maybe create the array yourself